# Create a vector according to multiple conditions contained in vectors

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements, grouping

Imagine I have this data.frame :

```
a <- c("Boy","Girl","Dog","Cat","Chair","Table")
b <- c(1:6)
df <- data.frame(a,b)
```

I would like to create a third column groupings elements in the first column according to predefined vectors :

```
human <- c("Boy","Girl") 
pet <- c("Dog","Cat")
object <- c("Chair","Table")
```

With this wished result :

```
df$Type <- c("Human","Human","Animal","Animal","Object","Object")
```

I managed to get it right for 2 groups but I don't know how to include the third one :

```
df$Type1 <- ifelse(df$a==human,"Human","Animal")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use nested ifelse() and use %in% instead of ==

```
ifelse(df$a %in% human, "Human", ifelse(df$a %in% pet, "Animal", "Object"))
```

Assuming there is nothing else it can be this will work

Comment: Thanks ! what does "nested" mean here if I may ask ?

Comment: An ifelse() within an ifelse(). I.e. if this, do this, else if this, do this, else do this. Lol

Answer (score 2):

You can keep adding groups like this:

```
df$Type <- NA
df$Type <- ifelse(df$a %in% human, "Human", df$Type)
df$Type <- ifelse(df$a %in% pet, "Animal", df$Type)
df$Type <- ifelse(df$a %in% object, "Object", df$Type)
```

Result:

```
      a b   Type
1   Boy 1  Human
2  Girl 2  Human
3   Dog 3 Animal
4   Cat 4 Animal
5 Chair 5 Object
6 Table 6 Object
```

Comment: It rocks ! Thanks

Comment: Actually that does not work with my longer and more complex data.set, I get this error message :   "the size of a lengthier object is not a multiple of a shorter object"

Answer (score 1):

You could create a vector that links the specific types to the categories, and then subset this vector with your data frame. Like this:

```
a <- c("Boy","Girl","Dog","Cat","Chair","Table")
b <- c(1:6)
df <- data.frame(a,b,stringsAsFactors = F) #Note, the stringsAsFactors = F

links <- c(
  "Boy" = "Human", 
  "Girl" = "Human",
  "Dog" = "Animal",
  "Cat" = "Animal",
  "Table" = "Object",
  "Chair" = "Object"
  )

df$Type <- links[df$a]
```

Output:

```
> df
      a b   Type
1   Boy 1  Human
2  Girl 2  Human
3   Dog 3 Animal
4   Cat 4 Animal
5 Chair 5 Object
6 Table 6 Object
```

Edit:

If there are a lot of values in human, pet, and object, my solution would require typing, e.g., `="human"` repeatedly. Here's the a way to create the look-up table that is probably easier to scale

```
links_A <- c(
  "Boy" = "Human", 
  "Girl" = "Human",
  "Dog" = "Animal",
  "Cat" = "Animal",
  "Chair" = "Object",
  "Table" = "Object"
  )

human <- c("Boy","Girl") 
pet <- c("Dog","Cat")
object <- c("Chair","Table")

links_B <- rep(c("Human", "Animal", "Object"), times = lengths(list(human, pet, object)))
names(links_B) <- c(human, pet, object)

identical(links_A, links_B) # TRUE
```

Comment: Thank your for your answer, I find it very intuitive but it is unhandy with larger vectors

Comment: Thanks. See the edit for a way that might be easier with larger vectors.